# Filtering Telerik MVC Grid on Date only (neglect time values)

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a column in Telerik MVC Grid which is of type DateTime. I want to only use the Date part of it for display and filtering. As a result, I used the following code

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<State>()
      .Name("tlkStateGrid")
      .Columns(col => {
          col.Bound(m => m.CreatedOn).Title("Created On").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
```

The Grid does display the Date (CreatedOn) in the format specified. However, the filtering doesn't work as expected. I think that while filtering, the time values are considered too by the Grid. So if two dates are same but having different time values, they are not considered 'equal'. 
How do I configure grid to neglect the time values and compare only dates, when filtering.

Note: I have posted similar question in Telerik MVC forums but no answer as yet.

Answer (score 2):

You could modify lambda expression to explicitly modify the CreatedOn property to be just a date. You'll get just the date component of the datetime object.

```
col.Bound(m => m.CreatedOn.Date)
```

You new code will now be as below.

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<State>()
      .Name("tlkStateGrid")
      .Columns(col => {
          col.Bound(m => m.CreatedOn.Date).Title("Created On").Format({0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
```

if CreatedOn is a nullable datetime you'll need to access its Value property before getting the Date component. See below.

```
col.Bound(m => m.CreatedOn.HasValue? m.CreatedOn.Value.Date : m.CreatedOn)
```

Comment: scartag, thanks for reply. The CreatedOn field is nullable datetime, so I used the col.Bound(m => m.CreatedOn.Value.Date) as suggested by you. However, I am getting "System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value", when I try to run the application.

Comment: I initially thought of doing the same but the Telerik Grid does not accept this kind of expression. The only expression allowed is field or property access expression. So if I use the modified code I am getting "System.InvalidOperationException: Bound columns require a field or property access expression".

Comment: @Nirvan Maybe you could modify your model a bit. you can extend it using a partial class if u don't want to mess things up. then add a new property CreatedOnDate then use this expression there. which would enable u use the CreatedOnDate field with the grid

Comment: I will try to do what you suggest. I will create a separate property as you suggested and mark it as [NotMapped] attribute. Then I will try to use this property in my grid. Will let you know if I succeed. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I modified my model to include a CreatedOnDate and then using the Value.Date expression. But that doesn't work either. The Telerik filtering module uses LINQ and such properties are not supported in LINQ. So I again get InvalidOperationException saying that the field cannot be used in LINQ. So I guess I will have to use some other approach. Let me know if you have one in mind.

Comment: @Nirvan You didn't need to use the Value.Date expression in the grid, only at the model level. Create a new property (CreatedOnDate) and in the getter is where u make a call to CreatedOn.Value.Date (check for nulls though).

Comment: I didn't use the Value.Date in grid. I used it in my model in the get{} of the CreatedOnDate property. But since the CreatedOnDate is not mapped to database, naturally it doesn't have any corresponding column to execute SQL on. This is where the LINQ to Entities fail and I get the InvalidOperationException. I think I need some different approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've created the following code which changes the way a date-filter is defined:

```
/// <summary>
/// Maps DateTime related filters.
/// * IsEqualTo filter is converted to ('x-date' is GreaterThanOrEqualTo 'SearchDate') AND ('x-date' is LessThan 'SearchDate' + 1 Day)
/// * IsNotEqualTo filter is converted to ('x-date' LessThan 'SearchDate') OR ('x-date' is GreaterThan 'SearchDate' + 1 Day) OR ('x-date' is NULL)
/// * IsLessThanOrEqualTo filter is converted to ('x-date' is LessThan 'SearchDate' + 1 Day)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="copyOfOriginalFilters">A copy from the filters.</param>
/// <param name="newFilters">The new filters</param>
protected void MapDateFilter(ReadOnlyCollection<IFilterDescriptor> copyOfOriginalFilters, IList<IFilterDescriptor> newFilters)
{
    newFilters.Clear();

    foreach (var currentFilter in copyOfOriginalFilters)
    {
        Type t = currentFilter.GetType();

        if (t == typeof(FilterDescriptor))
        {
            var filter = currentFilter as FilterDescriptor;

            if (filter.ConvertedValue.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                DateTime datePart = ((DateTime)filter.ConvertedValue).Date;

                if (filter.Operator == FilterOperator.IsEqualTo)
                {
                    var compositeFilter = new CompositeFilterDescriptor();
                    compositeFilter.FilterDescriptors.Add(new FilterDescriptor(filter.Member, FilterOperator.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo, datePart));
                    compositeFilter.FilterDescriptors.Add(new FilterDescriptor(filter.Member, FilterOperator.IsLessThan, datePart.AddDays(1)));
                    compositeFilter.LogicalOperator = FilterCompositionLogicalOperator.And;

                    newFilters.Add(compositeFilter);
                }
                else if (filter.Operator == FilterOperator.IsNotEqualTo)
                {
                    var compositeFilter = new CompositeFilterDescriptor();
                    compositeFilter.FilterDescriptors.Add(new FilterDescriptor(filter.Member, FilterOperator.IsLessThan, datePart));
                    compositeFilter.FilterDescriptors.Add(new FilterDescriptor(filter.Member, FilterOperator.IsGreaterThan, datePart.AddDays(1)));
                    compositeFilter.FilterDescriptors.Add(new FilterDescriptor(filter.Member, FilterOperator.IsEqualTo, null));
                    compositeFilter.LogicalOperator = FilterCompositionLogicalOperator.Or;

                    newFilters.Add(compositeFilter);
                }
                else if (filter.Operator == FilterOperator.IsLessThanOrEqualTo)
                {
                    newFilters.Add(new FilterDescriptor(filter.Member, FilterOperator.IsLessThan, datePart.AddDays(1)));
                }
                else
                {
                    newFilters.Add(filter);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                newFilters.Add(filter);
            }
        }
        else if (t == typeof(CompositeFilterDescriptor))
        {
            var filter = currentFilter as CompositeFilterDescriptor;

            int numberOfDateFilters = filter.FilterDescriptors.Where(fd =>
                fd is FilterDescriptor &&
                (fd as FilterDescriptor).ConvertedValue != null &&
                (fd as FilterDescriptor).ConvertedValue.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
                .Count();

            if (numberOfDateFilters == 2)
            {
                var firstFilter = filter.FilterDescriptors[0] as FilterDescriptor;
                firstFilter.Value = ((DateTime)firstFilter.ConvertedValue).Date;

                var secondFilter = filter.FilterDescriptors[1] as FilterDescriptor;
                secondFilter.Value = ((DateTime)secondFilter.ConvertedValue).Date;
            }
            else
            {
                MapDateFilter(new List<IFilterDescriptor>(filter.FilterDescriptors).AsReadOnly(), filter.FilterDescriptors);
            }

            newFilters.Add(filter);
        }
    }
}
```

This can be used like:

```
protected void MapGridCommand(GridCommand command)
{
    this.MapDateFilter(new List<IFilterDescriptor>(command.FilterDescriptors).AsReadOnly(), command.FilterDescriptors);
}
```